# call cors protect api from any fronend like postman call all api

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, frontend

exact issue:- call POST https://postman-echo.com/post API from react js Axios give cors error, is it possible? or any other frontend do this?

code sandbox:- https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-forked-gjj82c?file=/src/index.js:257-264

NOTE:- check error in network

I am working on some tasks where I need to call some other APIs from different domains and some of the APIs give me cors error.

my boundaries are

localhost, local IP, other IP, domain with port or subdomains

EX:-

```
http://localhost:5000/test
http://192.168.0.111:5000/test
http://3.91.432.163:5000/test
https://postman-echo.com/post
```

Any frontend language I can choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried multiple ways but can not solve it

but find 1 way to do this stuff using [cors-anywhere](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere)

I have created 1 server using this package and called blocked URL by using it

EX:- as in question call API using Axios with URL

http://localhost:6000/https://postman-echo.com/post

HERE http://localhost:6000 is my cors-anywhere server

and it works for me

**NOTE:-** you can use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ hosted server too(it is the demo of this package)